# Is Flyway's Context/JavaMigrationExecutor thread safe?

Tags: java, flyway

Let's say I have next class:

```java
public class MyMigration extends BaseJavaMigration {

    private static ExecutorService executorService;

    @Override
    public void migrate(Context context) throws Exception {
       // some code
       executorService.execute(() -> process(context, listOfIds));
    }

    private void process(Context context, List<Long> listOfIds) {
      context.getConnection()
            .prepareStatement(buildSql(listOfIds))
            .executeUpdate();
       }
    }
```

Is that possible to use Context in this way? Is Context/JavaMigrationExecutor thread safe?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It looks to me like you're trying to work against Flyway instead of with it. My guess would that this way, the next migration could start while your code is still doing things. Or it could even fail because Flyway things migration is completed and closed the connection of the context.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The thing is that before updating some values in DB I need to prepare them by requesting S3 bucket in AWS which contains about 1.5 objects, so it is very time consuming. I thought it would be possible to split it into several threads.

Comment: You have two problems: 1) although in theory JDBC connections are thread-safe, in practice it is just not a good idea to share a connection on multiple threads, 2) if you want to do this, you need to make sure that you actually wait for completion of the executor service (or the tasks you schedule), so the execution is contained within the migration. That said, I'm not sure migrating 1.5 (?) objects (I'm guessing 1.5 million?) from S3 belongs within a Flyway migration.

Comment: Yes. It is 1.5 millions. My bad. I agree with you that Flyway is not compatible with such operations but project that I am in now using this approach broadly and did not succeed to convince them to change approach. About sharing connection - I was not going to share one connections between threads. I thought that context.getConnection() returns new one every time. If it is not - then my question is pointless at all.